# How to find out what Property's a trigger accepts

Tags: wpf

In XAML we can perform the following trigger

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Trigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0" />
        </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

My question is how does some one know what property it accepts. How could I know if it accepts MouseOver or OnMouseOver (without testing every combination).

So, in case the above is too broad,  if you wanted to know what triggers were accepted for the LIstBoxItem, how would you find out?

Comment: It depends on the type on the ControlTempalte.

Comment: How do I find out for all... I mean, there must be a way of telling, via MSDN or via the Object Browser or some other means. If you wanted to know what triggers were accepted for the LIstBoxItem, how would you find out?

Comment: when you type them in. you will get an error on your xaml stating that he does not know this property... 

other then that msdn